# Excel files with passwords not responsive from network drive

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a couple decent sized excel files (one 18,442 KB, another 11,088 KB) that have passwords. Yesterday I could open them without problems. Today I found my computer had restarted itself after a forced Windows Update, and now these files will hang and tell me Excel is not responding.

If I copy these files to my hard drive they open instantly.

I have another file on the network drive that is only 56 KB but doesn't have a password. It would normally open instantly...today it takes 5-7 seconds.

These are the updates that happened over night:
- Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in
- Update for Windows 7 (KB2552343)
- Update for Windows 7 (KB2545698)
- Security Update for .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 SP1 x86 (KB2518869)
- Update for Windows 7 (KB2547666)
- Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 x86 (KB2478663)
- Security Update for .NET Framework 3.5.1 on windows 7 SP1 x86 (KB2478662)
- Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 on Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 x86 (KB2518870)

My suspicions make me think it's the File Validation Add-in. Microsoft's website for that update says a known issue is "Opening files from a network share that have many charts or points of data will take longer to open in Office 2003."

As you can guess, I'm using Windows 7 (32 bit) and Office 2003.

Does anybody have any info that would confirm my suspicions or help me figure out what's going on? I looked for the File Validation Add-in to uninstall it, and it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: update: I left one of the files alone while excel was trying to open it, and it does eventually open. It certainly sounds like the File Validation Add-in is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue but we have been successful in removing the "Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in" from Add-Remove programs.
Now when we open spreadsheets they open at normal speed.
Before removing the add-in Excel took so long to open a file most users thought that Excel had crashed

Comment: You, sir, are a genius! For some reason I didn't think to check the Add-Remove Programs section to remove it. Thank you!

Comment: This is absolutely the reason+1

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft Office File Validation Add-in" caused dramatic slowdowns when opening Excel 2003 files from a network location.  I removed it and got instantly better results (i.e. returned to normal).  I checked the box on Microsoft Update to "not show me this again".